# Adding style to CakePHP automatically created input div

Tags: css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, html-input

CakePHP creates a div that automatically wraps any of its input tags that are built with the formhelper as followed:

```
$this->formhelper->input('something');
```

Such that the output looks about as followed:

```
<div class='input'>
    <input />
</div>
```

I know that there is a way to add classes to the input tag i.e.

```
$this->formhelper->input('text', array('class' => 'some_css'));
```

But how would you add a style to the div that is automatically created by CakePHP. This might be something where the core needs to be hacked, but I want to know if there is a better way to do this, so that I get something as followed:

```
<div class='input other_class_I_want_here'>
    <input />
</div>
```

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: For starters I would recommend reading the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) - also using `$this->Form->` here instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add a new class to the div.

```
$this->formhelper->input('text', array('div'=>array('class'=>'divClass'),'class' => 'some_css'));
```

should actually output

```
<div class='input divClass'>
    <input class='other_class_I_want_here' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is certainly correct. And works beautifully if you only require adding a class in a one (or a few) specific locations.

However, anyone arriving here looking for a way to add a class to input div wrappers application-wide (ex: if you're using a front-end framework which often requires a specific class name be added to input wrappers to enable auto-styles) there is a **MUCH** better solution. That being, a custom FormHelper.

> 1. In the App/View/Helper directory create and save a file "MySuperCoolFormHelper.php"
> 2. Place the following code in the file:

```
    App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');
    
    class MySuperCoolFormHelper extends FormHelper {

        protected function _divOptions($options) {
            if(isset($options['div'])
                $options['div'] .= ' class1 class2 class3'; //note the prefixing space
            else
                $options['div'] = 'class1 class2 class3';

            return parent::_divOptions($options);
        }
    }
```

> 3. To use this new form helper globally, add the following code to your AppController:

```
    public $helpers = array(
        'Form' => array(
            'className' => 'MySuperCoolFormHelper'
        )
        //The rest of your helper inits
    );
```

... and BLAMMO you're done!

Comment: Good question, sorry for omitting!! In your AppController, where you initialize the FormHelper,  you simply initialize it slightly differently:

public $helpers = array(
 'Form' => array(
  'className' => 'MySuperCoolFormHelper'
 )
);

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3:
For applying 'form-group' to DIV and 'form-control' to the input field

```
<?= 
$this->Form->control('year', [
    'type' => 'select', 
    'value' => $year, 
    'options' => $years, 
    'label' => false, 
    'class' => 'form-control', 
    'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group">{{content}}</div>']
    ]); 
?>
```